# How to limit a function's cosine value as it approaches 0

Tags: numpy

How do I get a cosine to peak up to a certain value as it hits 0? With the above code, the y-value peaks to infinity as it approaches 0.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

amp = 1
time = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)

signal = np.cos(1 * np.pi * time) * abs(1/time)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.ylim(-4, 4)
plt.plot(time, signal, color="black")
plt.savefig('output.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0,
            transparent=True)
```

Put another way, based on my google-fu, how can I create a symmetrical exponentially decaying sinusoid with a maximum y-value as it approaches 0?

Comment: if you would like such a function described mathematically please consider posting your question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) if this is a question about implementation

Comment: Whoops, thanks! Thought about using math.stackexchange, but thought this would be better since it was numpy. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\alpha e^{-\beta x^2}cos(x)$ where $\alpha$ is your peak and $\beta$ is proportional to the strength of the decay

This one's slightly longer and the peak is at $\alpha+1$ but the graph is easier to manipulate:

$cos(x)e^{-\beta x^2}+\alpha e^{-x^2}$

Comment: That was perfect. Thanks!!